# Extend the standard fields for a CE with a plugin in typo3

Tags: plugins, configuration, typo3, backend

I have an own frontend plugin and I want an extra configuration tab with fields when I click on [edit(**Content Element**)] in the backend of typo3.
I've tried the following explanation:
https://typo3.sascha-ende.de/docs/development/extensions/add-a-tab/
I've changed the pages.php (*this was wrong, for CE's its **tt_content.php***) in Configuration/TCA/Overrides and also created the tables in ext_tables.sql.
Unfortunately nothing appeared in the backend.
Can somenone please help me; thanks.

Comment: Do you want to add the configuration to the page or to the plugin content element? These two are different. Page is handled in `pages` and content elements in `tt_content`.

Answer (score 0):

try this as closing line in tt_content.php:

```
\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::addToAllTCAtypes(
    'tt_content',
    '--div--;My own tab,inputfield1,inputfield2',
    '',
    'after:layout'
);
```

the third entry determens the List of specific types to add the tab to (if you leave it empty, it's inserted for all types), and the last (missing in the example of sasha) the position ...

**edit;** I could not figure out that the fields where supposed to appear in tt_content, now I switched from pages

Comment: The problem is that this does noz work either. Even after cleaning the cache and deleting everything in the typo3temp folder

Comment: again: these changes are done for the table `pages`. your plugin is stored in `tt_content`. you need to use the file `Configuration/TCA/Overrides/tt_conetnt.php` and you should add the fields to `tt_content`, so make sure the first parameter of `addToAllTCAtypes()` is `'tt_content'`

Comment: Thank you Bernd, that was the solution :)

Comment: How did Bernd figure you where adding fields to tt_content ??